# How to stop function from Freaking out when Ajax calls are made on Scroll Position?

Tags: jquery, scroll, javascript

Here is the URL to the project im working on:

http://www.buymyoldiphone.com/Ajax_Tests/TodTom/Social%20V2.0/NEW/index.html

I tried to allow it to load new content (using ajax) when the scrollbar was about 3/4ths the way down the page:

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 

    var height = $(window).height();
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();                                     

    if(scrollTop > (height*3)) {
        numRes = numRes + 20;
        reloadContent();
    }
});
```

But as you can see (if you look at the URL), it just goes crazy until everything disappears.

And coding advice?

**EDIT**

The function seems to work just fine with:

```
$('#loadmore_btn').live('click',function() {
        numRes = numRes + 20;
        reloadContent();
});
```

Comment: +1 - for functions that freak out!

Comment: Switching the function to decaf may help calm it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem few days ago. Here is how i fixed:

1) Right at the begining of document.ready, i put this:

```
$('body').data('isAJAX', false);
$('body').ajaxStart(function(){
    $('body').data('isAJAX', true);
}).ajaxStop(function(){
    $('body').data('isAJAX', false);
});
```

2) then, when i make an ajax call i just check:

```
if(!$('body').data('isAJAX')){ 
// make my ajax call
}
```

Sure, i only had one possible ajax call, so was pretty eassy for me, but... it may help you too :)

Comment: This seems to work pretty well. The only problem I have is that it still fires the function like crazy. Thanks for the code

Answer (score 0):

set a timeout to delay calling the ajax.

```
var _timeout;

$(window).scroll(function () { 
    clearTimeout(_timeout);
    var height = $(window).height();
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();                                     

    if(scrollTop > (height*3)) {
        numRes = numRes + 20;
        _timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                   reloadContent();
                }, 50);
    }
});
```

The timeout doesn't have to be long, just something to delay the call a little bit because the scroll event fires a lot.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, see the URL. It doesn't seem to write the function now

Comment: Pass function references directly to `setTimeout`, not strings.

Comment: @locrizak Thanks. Seems to be working better now, but still having an issue with it erasing everything. It may be an issue with a different function though

Comment: its most likely in your complete function.

Comment: * not literally a button, but you get the idea

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem,,

Turns out, scrollTop doesn't give you a ratio of your distance down, just a number to represent your scroll position - so if your 3/4ths way down the page, and 50% more content is loaded - the scrollTop number will stay the same if your scroll position isn't moved. The total scroll distance just increases by 50%.

So I decided to use the height of the container which wraps all of my document elements to represent the total scroll distance, and I just found the ratio of the distance (scrollTop/Total Distance) at .75 to represent the page load.

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 

    var height = $(window).height();
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); 
    var scrollAll = $('#container').height();
    var scrollRatio = (scrollTop/scrollAll);

    if(scrollRatio > .75) {
            if(!$('body').data('isAJAX')){ 
                numRes = numRes + 20;
                eReload = 1; //reload all content
                AddOr = 1;
                reloadContent();
                //alert(scrollRatio) will always be around .75
            }
    }
});
```

Thank you lonut Staicu for providing the code above to make the function run smoothly

Comment: your welcome. you should mark my answer though :) However, you can do this: `if(scrollRatio > .75 && !$('body').data('isAJAX')) {` and remove the second `if`